# JSoup timeout on certain URLs from certain server

Tags: dom, jsoup

Launching JSoup script from my machine => works fine.

Launching the same script from my remote server => throws `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out` error.

I reproduce the problem only with certain URLs. I tried launching the same script on other web pages from this remote server and it went ok.

My script:

```
private Document getDom(String root){
    Document dom = null;
    try {
        dom = Jsoup.connect(root).get();
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
        try {
            dom = Jsoup.parse(new URL(root).openStream(), "UTF-8", root);
        } catch (IOException e2){
            System.out.println(e2);
        }
    }
    return dom;
}
```

`root` is the target URL, in my example https://hightest.nc/sitemap.xml.

Any idea where the problem could come from?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this code and it returns your XML for me when I fixed your catch block.The first catch didn't seem to be properly closed. The other potential problem on connection timeouts is you're not adding a userAgent. Try this code block below which I have tested and it works for me.

From the server you can also try and adjust the timeout on the connection to see if that will work for you. Try to perhaps adjust it to a higher timeout.
.timeout​(7000)

```
 private Document getDom(String root){
        Document dom = null;
        try {
            dom = Jsoup.connect(root)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) 
           AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36")
                    .get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
            try {
                dom = Jsoup.parse(new URL(root).openStream(), "UTF-8", root);

            } catch (IOException e2){

                System.out.println(e2);
            }

          return dom;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your insights, I will try this as soon as possible and tell you if it works.